# Composer error - Your requirements could not be resolved - Laravel 4.2 on Mediatemple

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, mediatemple

I'm getting a problem reported from composer when running `php -d allow_url_fopen=On composer.phar install` on mediatemple.

This reports back saying `laravel/framework v4.2.6 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.`

I've updated my php version to be 5.5, but i'm not sure if the above problem is referring to my php version or the laravel/framework package when it says "no matching package found".

when I run the above command, it shows that it is 'installing dependencies (including require-dev)' but i get the problem reported above.

my minimum stability is set to "stable"

could someone help clarify?

Comment: It's quite possible that the php you upgraded to isn't the same one as the one your command-line interface uses. Can you run ``php -v`` from the terminal and see which version it reports back?

Comment: @JoelHinz ah you're right! it still states 5.3. what should i do in this case? i can see that mediatemple has added a .htaccess file with php-latest .php, not sure if tht does anything

Comment: No, that likely doesn't change anything. What you need to do depends on your operating system, and on the method with which you installed php. To be honest, I'm not an expert on that, but there are lots of questions about upgrading command-line php here on so. :)

Comment: @JoelHinz it seems that running php -v in the terminal won't report back the right version as it doesn't consider the php.ini file for the domain

Comment: so if that's the case, php version should be good, not sure why i get the above error

Comment: Well, terminal php is probably not the same as web server php. Running ``php -v`` always gives the right version that the terminal is using. But you could also run ``php -i | grep php.ini`` to see which php.ini file is used in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was using php v5.3 on the CLI while I was running php 5.5 on the domain successfully as they had told me.

In order to use the latest php version on the CLI, i had to run `php-latest composer.phar install` instead of `php composer.phar install`

I found this link helpful: https://yesdevnull.net/2014/03/using-php-54-cli-on-media-temples-grid-hosting/